# Button OnClickListener not working

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I am new to Android. I am trying to get input from the EditText and displaying it in TextView with the help of button. When I click the button nothing happens. Please help, here is my MainActivity.java code -

```
package com.example.addname;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button b1;
    TextView v1;
    EditText t1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        t1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        v1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(t1.getText().toString()=="")
                {

                    v1.setText(t1.getText().toString());
                }

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

and here is my activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend comparing strings with `.equals()` since Objects compared with `==` usually fails (`==` compares references, not Object content).

```
if(t1.getText().toString().equals("")))
```

in your case though,since you're comparing an empty String, you can also use

```
if (t1.getText().toString().length == 0)
```

Then note that once you set the text, you're setting `v1`'s text to an empty string since your logic indicates that only upon an empty string you set `v1`'s text. So I'd recommend getting rid of the `if` altogether:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
     v1.setText(t1.getText().toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
if(t1.getText().toString()=="")
{

   v1.setText(t1.getText().toString());
}
```

You can use

```
if(t1.getText().isEmpty())  // isEmpty() is only available from API 9 and Above
{

  v1.setText(t1.getText().toString());
}
```

or this

```
if(t1.getText().trim().length == 0)
{

  v1.setText(t1.getText().toString());
}
```

Don't compare strings using `==`. You're actually comparing reference of an object. To compare strings, use `equals()` method.